# Unknown storage : Swap space : ERROR in nagios

Tags: snmp, nagios

We have a Nagios server running on Linux and one of the host machine is running on Linux.

When I try to manually run the command to get the information of swap space using SNMP I am getting the output, but it is not reflecting on the dashboard.

Can anybody help me?

For your reference, please find the output from manually running the command.
`check_snmp_swap.pl -H IP Address -C public -m -w 80 -c 90`

```
Swap Space: 0%used(26MB/95998MB) /data: 0%used(188MB/129704MB) Real  
Memory: 16%used(10263MB/64444MB) /: 62%used(30070MB/48432MB) Memory   
Buffers: 0%used(239MB/64444MB) (<80%) : OK
```

But in dashboard I'm not able to see the status of only Swap space, but I'm able to see the status of CPU and RAM.

Answer (score 0):

Check your service definition for check_snmp_swap.  Make sure that the service is registered, meaning you set `register 1` in the service definition.

For example:

```
define service{
    host_name       check_snmp_swap
    service_description check-swap
    check_command       check_snmp_swap!public!80!90
    max_check_attempts  5
    check_interval  5
    retry_interval  3
    check_period        24x7
    notification_interval   30
    notification_period 24x7
    notification_options    w,c,r
    contact_groups      linux-admins
    register    1
}
```

Also check the command definition for check_snmp_swap.  Make sure that the correct community string gets passed into the command -- in this case, `public`.

**EDIT:**

From the configuration information you posted in the comments, I think you have a bit of confusion regarding **service definitions** and **service template definitions**.
It looks like you posted a **template** - which as a template, really **should** have it's `register` value set to `0` to indicate it's a template.

Now a **real service definition** may inherit some settings from a service template.  The purpose of this is to save you from having to re-enter the same information over and over again when you create service definitions.
You can override the settings inherited from the service template by explicitly defining those settings in the service definition.

You should create a service definition that looks something like this:

```
define service{
    host_name       check_snmp_swap
    use             generic-service
    service_description check-swap
    check_command       check_snmp_swap
    max_check_attempts  5
    check_interval  10
    retry_interval  2
    check_period        24x7
    notification_interval   30
    notification_period 24x7
    notification_options    w,u,c,r
    contact_groups      admins
    register    1
}
```

Then restart your nagios service:

`service nagios restart`

Comment: Hi I have checked the config files as per your suggestion But still im not able to rectify the error.

Comment: Please find the config files and let me know what ichanges needs to be made.                                                                                                            define command {
        command_name                    check_snmp_swap
        command_line                    $USER1$/snmp_check/check_snmp_swap.pl -C public -H $HOSTADDRESS$ -m 'Swap space' -w 80 -c 90 -f
        register                        1
}

Comment: ## Linux Machine Performance Check via SNMP##
define command {
        command_name                    check_cpu_snmp
        command_line                    $USER1$/snmp_check/check_cpu_snmp.bash -H $HOSTADDRESS$ -C public -w 80 -c 90
        register                         1
}

Comment: Thanks for posting your command definition.  You also need to check your service definition.  It too needs to have "register 1" defined.

Comment: I have checked the service definition, register 1 is defined in the service config file as well.

Comment: define service{
        name                            linux_service         ; The 'name' of this service template
        hostgroup_name                 linux-production-servers,linux-development-servers,linux-license-servers,project-linux-servers,project-windows-servers
                normal_check_interval           10        
        retry_check_interval            2                     contact_groups                  admins                  
        notification_options            w,u,c,r             register                        1      }

Comment: My concern is why I am not able to monitor only swap for a Linux machine when I am able to monitor CPU and Ram for same machine

Comment: I've updated my answer based on the configuration information you posted in the comments.